# c# Find missing sequence number on object using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list containing a class and has a property of integer called `TransactNo`.

found this in another post

`var list = new List<int>(new[] { 1, 2, 4, 7, 9 });
 var result = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Except(list);`

how to use this in an array or list of object scenario?

```
var list<myclass> obj = new list<myclass>();
var result = Enumerable.Range(obj.transactNo[0],obj.transactNo[100]).Except(obj);
```

I encounter an error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS1929  '`IEnumerable<int>`' does not contain a definition for 'Except' and the best extension method overload '`Queryable.Except<<anonymous type: int TransNo>>(IQueryable<<anonymous type: int TransNo>>, IEnumerable<<anonymous type: int TransNo>>)`' requires a receiver of type '`IQueryable<<anonymous type: int TransNo>>`'

```
public class myclass
{
    public int TransactNo { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: how does your myclass look like?

Comment: Have you added `using System.Linq`?

Comment: It's hard to know which are your *actual* problems when you've provided pseudo-code - `var list<myclass> obj = new list<myclass>();` won't work to start with, because C# is case sensitive and the class is `List<T>` rather than `list<T>`. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: `public class myclass
    {
        public int TransactNo { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    }`

Comment: No, don't add a comment. Add a [mcve] *in the question*. Not just the `myclass` class - a complete which we can try to compile. You've only provided snippets so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this ?

```
var result = Enumerable.Range(obj[0].TransactNo, obj[100].TransactNo)
.Except(obj.Select(x=> x.TransactNo));
```

.Except method needs list of integer, not list of objects. Thats why you got error.

Hope helps,